# Flutter Firebase get sum of elements from data

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have been able to group data from a field. However I want get the sum of element in a field for each group. But I can't figure that out. Can anyone help me? Or is there a better approach to go this?
I need help, please. Thank you.

```
StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collectionGroup(widget.userRequestCollection)
            .where("Pay", isEqualTo: "Paid")
            .snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return const CircularProgressIndicator();
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text(widget.errorString);
          }

          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return GroupedListView(
              elements: snapshot.data!.docs,
              groupBy: (element) => element['DepartureDate'],
              groupSeparatorBuilder: (String groupByValue) =>
                  Text(groupByValue),
              itemBuilder: (context, dynamic element) {
                var col = FirebaseFirestore.instance
                .collectionGroup(widget.userRequestCollection);
            final countVal = col.count().get();
            final aggregates = col
                .where("Pay", isEqualTo: "Paid")
                .where("DepartureTimestamp",
                    isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: Timestamp.fromDate(
                        DateTime(element["DepartureDate"])))
                .where("DepartureTimestamp",
                    isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: Timestamp.fromDate(
                        DateTime(element["DepartureDate"])
                            .add(const Duration(days: 1))))
                .aggregate(
                  sum(element["AmountPaid"]),
                  average(element["AmountPaid#"]),
                  count(),
                )
                .get();
              },
              order: GroupedListOrder.ASC,
            );
            
          }
          return const Center(
            child: Text("No data"),
          );
        },
      )
```

[image: code]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the (pretty new) [sum operator](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/aggregation-queries#use_the_sum_aggregation) for this, I have an example of how to use that in Flutter [here](https://zapp.run/edit/firestore-sumavg-aggregations-zra606wira70). From that:

```
final startAt = Timestamp.fromDate(DateTime(2024, 01, 03));
final endBefore = Timestamp.fromDate(DateTime(2024, 01, 04));
final aggregates = await col
  .where('timestamp', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: startAt)
  .where('timestamp', isLessThan: endBefore)
  .aggregate(
    sum('latency'),
    average('latency'),
    count(),
  ).get();
print('''
  Logs on Jan 3:
    count=${aggregates.count}
    sum of latency=${aggregates.getSum("latency")}, 
    average latency=${aggregates.getAverage("latency")}
''');
```

And the relevant dependencies from the pubspec.yaml file in there:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cloud_firestore: ^4.14.0
  firebase_core: ^2.24.2
  firebase_auth: ^4.4.1
```

My data model is different from yours, but you should be able to similarly `aggregate(sum('AmountPaid'))` on the query, and then get the value with `snapshot.getSum("AmountPaid")`.

Comment: Is there a dependency for getting the aggregate()? I'm trying to use the .aggregate() but it's saying the aggregate is not defined

Comment: Did you check the second link in my answer? That zapp.run link has the full working code, including the dependencies. --- If you have the correct plugins, but it still doesn't work, check the version. The sum and average operations were added not too long ago, so you'll want to make sure you're on the latest build.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm new to this. I checked the second link but I don't know what to do with it. I copied the code as it's is but the ".aggregate" is still not working.  If the link is something I need to download and install, how do I do that. --- What plugins do I need and what version?

Comment: The link to zapp.run provides a working code sample that you can run and copy from. You can find the dependencies in the [`pubspec.yaml` file](https://zapp.run/edit/firestore-sumavg-aggregations-zra606wira70?entry=lib/main.dart&file=pubspec.yaml) in there.

Comment: The dependencies you are talking about I have them. I even run flutter upgrade yesterday to update all my dependencies. But the ".aggregate" is still not working. Could you please suggest a different way of getting the sum of items in the field which is arranged in according to dates. Example. I want to get the total amount paid on daily bases. That's why I put the field in groups. But the problem is how to get the sum on the daily basis

Comment: The way to use the server-side aggregation operators is as I show in my answer and in the link. If you run the zapp.run link, do you see that it calculates an average and sum? If that roughly equivalent to what you need to accomplish? If so, rather than asking me to write another example for you, I recommend you actually reproduce the problem you have doing that in your own code in a similar fashion (zapp.run or similar site), so that we are all looking at the same working and non-working samples.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256838/discussion-between-ebenezer-ocansey-and-frank-van-puffelen).

Answer (score 0):

how about this?

```
StreamBuilder(
    stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collectionGroup(widget.userRequestCollection)
        .where("Pay", isEqualTo: "Paid")
        .snapshots(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
        return const CircularProgressIndicator();
      } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
        return Text(widget.errorString);
      }

      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        return GroupedListView(
          elements: snapshot.data!.docs,
          groupBy: (element) => element['DepartureDate'],
          groupSeparatorBuilder: (String groupByValue) =>
              Text(groupByValue),
          itemBuilder: (context, dynamic element) {
             // --- new code
             double sum = element
                .map((e) => e.data()['AmountPaid'])
                .reduce((value, element) => value + element);;
             // ---
             return Text("$sum");
          },
          order: GroupedListOrder.ASC,
        );
        
      }
      return const Center(
        child: Text("No data"),
      );
    },
  )
```

Comment: The log is returning NoSuchMethodError: 'map'. Is there another way, please?